# Digitalocean Apps platform run time error - "workspace" directory is getting added

Tags: flask, runtime-error, digital-ocean

I could successfully deploy python/flask app on Digitalocean's Apps Platform.

Now its giving runtime error

app runtime log error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ‘/**workspace**/static/flora_title/Anacardiaceae_Buchanania cochinchinensis_1_Title1.JPG’

so it looks like the “workspace” directory is getting added to my html static data paths, which i don’t expect. This is causing all my static file paths simply inaccessible.

Wondering what could be the solution here? this is first time I am deploying app in DO Apps platform.

### Runtime Log as below:

[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:01] [2022-05-03 17:21:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:01] [2022-05-03 17:21:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:01] [2022-05-03 17:21:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:01] [2022-05-03 17:21:01 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:01] OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30] [2022-05-03 17:21:30,414] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30] Traceback (most recent call last):
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/species_visualization.py", line 37, in index
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     return render_template("HomePage.html", all_speciesj = all_speciesj)
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 148, in render_template
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     return _render(
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in _render
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     rv = template.render(context)
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1291, in render
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     self.environment.handle_exception()
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 926, in handle_exception
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/templates/HomePage.html", line 80, in top-level template code
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_cdn.py", line 54, in url_for
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     values['t'] = int(os.path.getmtime(path))
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/genericpath.py", line 55, in getmtime
[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30]     return os.stat(filename).st_mtime

**[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/workspace/static/flora_title/Anacardiaceae_Buchanania cochinchinensis_1_Title1.JPG'**

[onefloracdn] [2022-05-03 17:21:30] 10.244.35.126 - - [03/May/2022:17:21:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.32"

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be another 'gem' of a stupid question..but thats ok. Will answer myself..

I did not put my static files in App's platform...simple

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that is running into issues with DigitalOcean app platform and Flask... it took me a couple of days to figure it all out and troubleshoot.

So, to save you some time, I created a starter project template with instructions on how to get a Flask app with postgresql setup and running for the app platform for anyone that is interested.

Here's a link to the starter project: https://github.com/heyaustinwood/flask-do-app-platform

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).